# How to correctly reverse a numpy array in 2 dimensions?

Tags: arrays, numpy, reverse, flip

I am trying to reverse an array in 2D which sounds easy but when I use np.flip or slicing method, it does not work properly. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
t
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8]])

t[:,::-1]
array([[4, 3, 2, 1],
   [8, 7, 6, 5]])

np.flip(t, axis=1)
array([[4, 3, 2, 1],
   [8, 7, 6, 5]])

np.flip(t, axis=0)
array([[5, 6, 7, 8],
   [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

What I want is the following:

```
t
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [8, 7, 6, 5]])
```

I want to reverse the elements of the 2nd dimension but keep the 1st dimension unchanged.

Comment: you want to reverse the 2nd *row* only

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: `t[1,::-1]` reverses that row, but it doesn't do it in-place.  You have to write that back to `t`.

Comment: Ok I see that works but I want the new modified 2D array to use for later. Why doesn't np.flip work?

Comment: np.array([t[0,:],t[1,::-1]])
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [8, 7, 6, 5]])

I got it to work by doing the above. The question is this efficient?

Comment: `t[1,:] = t[1,::-1]` might be a bit better if you don't need or want an whole new array.

Comment: t[:,::-1] did the trick.